# xbar rounding up and application of last

Tags: kdb

```
q) t:([]time:(2021.01.31D17:50:19.986000000;2021.01.31D18:01:32.894000000;2021.01.31D18:02:08.884000000;2021.01.31D18:25:25.984000000;2021.01.31D18:25:27.134000000;2021.01.31D18:25:28.834000000;2021.01.31D18:25:29.934000000);val:(3.2;2.9;3.9;6.8;5.0;3.0;2.2);sym:(`AUD;`AUD;`AUD;`AUD;`AUD;`AUD;`AUD))

time                          val sym
-------------------------------------
2021.01.31D17:50:19.986000000 3.2 AUD
2021.01.31D18:01:32.894000000 2.9 AUD
2021.01.31D18:02:08.884000000 3.9 AUD
2021.01.31D18:25:25.984000000 6.8 AUD
2021.01.31D18:25:27.134000000 5   AUD
2021.01.31D18:25:28.834000000 3   AUD
2021.01.31D18:25:29.934000000 2.2 AUD

prices: 0!select last val by sym, 0D00:01+0D00:01 xbar time from t

sym x                             val
-------------------------------------
AUD 2021.01.31D17:51:00.000000000 3.2
AUD 2021.01.31D18:02:00.000000000 2.9
AUD 2021.01.31D18:03:00.000000000 3.9
AUD 2021.01.31D18:26:00.000000000 2.2
```

for the first row in prices for e.g. how does q work to ensure that the val is **not** the last value between `2021.01.31D17:51:00.000000000` and `2021.01.31D17:52:00.000000000` but that between `2021.01.31D17:50:00.000000000` and `2021.01.31D17:51:00.000000000`? Asking because the command involves `0D00:01+0D00:01 xbar time` and not just `0D00:01 xbar time`.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kdb still reads right-of-left within the sub-components of a select statement, so

```
0D00:01+0D00:01 xbar time
```

is read as

```
0D00:01 xbar time
```

and the additional `0D00:01` is added after the xbar operation. So the `0D00:01+` really only effects the "display" of the result, not the values used in the grouping.

This is what you possibly think kdb would confuse it for:

```
0D00:01 xbar 0D00:01+time
```

The above would return last value between 17:51 and 17:52 since the times are bumped up *before* the xbar/grouping rather than *after* the xbar/grouping but the results would actually be the same because this is really just a labelling exercise.

Comment: prices: 0!select last val by sym, 0D00:01 xbar 0D00:01+time from t returns the same result  as that showed in my question although I would expect it to behave like you said.

Comment: You're right - in this example there's actually no difference because "grouping by time then labelling it as the next minute" is the same as "labelling as the next minute and then grouping by time". But in the more general case this may not always be the case so I was generalising, and moreso trying to get across the point of the order of operation in this scenario